# How to delegate constructors for std::variant?

Tags: c++, constructor, std-variant

I have two structs `A1` and `A2` and another struct `B` has constructors for both. How do I write a delegating constructor for `std::variant<A1,A2>`?

```
#include <variant>
struct A1 {};
struct A2 {};
using A = std::variant<A1, A2>;

struct B {
  B(const A1 &){}
  B(const A2 &){}
  B(const A& a)
      :B(a) // <--- what do I put here to delegate like std::visit ?
  {}
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    return 0;
}
```

I am looking for a clean modern way in the spirit of `std::visit`. I know that I can use a static member function to construct a `B` instance from `A` using `std::visit` and a lambda but that's not what I am asking for since I want to rely on implicit type conversion from `A` to `B`.

Comment: You cannot, the constructor call must be resolved at compile-time but which variant is active is only known at runtime. The lambda + `std::visit` wrapper returning `B` is the best I think there is.

Comment: Not ideal, but perhaps `*this = ...` in a `visit()`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat This is an option. Thanks. Should be optimized away right? Or at least call cheap move constructor.

Comment: @phinz Of course implicit conversions are possible during delegation, just any as they work for any function calls, but there is no implicit conversion from `std::variant<A1,A2>` to `B` just because `B` can be implicitly converted from all of the types.

Comment: Should be at worst a move, yes. Might not be entirely optimized away, depending on the class.

Comment: That's not an answer to the question but I think I will just wrap the `std::variant` in a struct `A` and write a conversion operator to B where I use the `std::visit` + lambda approach to get implicit conversion from `A` to `B`.

Comment: I would prefer to keep it simple and drop one set of overloads. For example drop `B(const A1 &)` and `B(const A2 &)` letting implicit conversion to `A` take over. Exact details what `B` contains and what is `A1` and `A2` would have impact on my final decision which approach is better (answer with copy ctor or something else).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can use the copy constructor,
you can do this (not scalable but work in this case) :

```
struct B {
      B(const A1 &){}
      B(const A2 &){}
      B(const A& a)
          : B((a.index() == 0) ? B(std::get<0>(a)) : B(std::get<1>(a)))
      {}
    
    };
```

alternative with std::visit :

```
struct B {
   B(const A1 &){}
   B(const A2 &){}
   B(const A& a) : 
       B(std::visit([](const auto & x)
            {
                 return B(x);
            },a))
      {}
};
```

Comment: @phinz • this is really a delegate-delegate, since it uses the copy-or-move constructor.  If that is okay, you could just use `std::visit` in a lambda, presuming that is deemed not ugly.  (Update: and jls28 delivers!)

Comment: Yes [this does compile](https://godbolt.org/z/vcWPdzbjo), but this uses temporary instance of `B` to delegate to copy constructor. So it will fail copy/move constructor are not available. Also if `B` is complex heavy object (not just toy example) this extra copy can be problematic.

Comment: @Marek R : yes I agree with you.